# Set bit in a varbinary

Tags: sql-server

I have a varbinary column and a bit number which can be bigger than 32. How can I set/test a bit having it's number in the varbinary column?

I tried to do

```
convert(varbinary(max), power(2, @bit_number))
```

to get me varbinary, but it is limited to float size numbers.

There is an extended stored procedure which can do OR of two varbinaries in our DB but I need to pass this long varbinary mask, or maybe there is a way to update some byte in varbinary knowing it's number?

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert the varbinary to a string, manipulate it, and convert it back.  For example, try this:

```
DECLARE @Foo varbinary(max)
SELECT @Foo = 0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef

DECLARE @Temp varchar(max)
SELECT @Temp = CONVERT(varchar(max), @Foo, 1)
DECLARE @ByteOffset integer;
SELECT @ByteOffset = 3 --offset into varbinary to access
DECLARE @GetValue binary(1)
SELECT @GetValue = CONVERT(binary(1), '0x' + SUBSTRING(@Temp, (@ByteOffset * 2) + 3, 2),1 )
PRINT @GetValue -- fetch the value at @ByteOffset

DECLARE @SetValue binary(1)
SELECT @SetValue = 0x04 --value to modify
DECLARE @Foo2 varbinary(max)
SELECT @Foo2 = CONVERT(varbinary(max), SUBSTRING(@Temp, 1, (@ByteOffset * 2) + 2) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @SetValue, 1), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(@Temp, (@ByteOffset * 2) + 5, LEN(@Temp)), 1)
PRINT @Foo2 --contains the new varbinary with @ByteOffset updated with @SetValue
```