# How to set a specific bit in a BINARY or VARBINARY variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, binary

I'm trying to update the value of one or many specific bits inside a bytes array.

```
DECLARE @byteArray BINARY(32)
DECLARE @startIndex INTEGER
DECLARE @endIndex INTEGER
DECLARE @pointer INTEGER

SET @byteArray = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
SET @startIndex = 3
SET @endIndex = 5
SET @pointer = @startIndex

WHILE @pointer <= @endIndex
BEGIN
    SET @byteArray[@pointer] = 1 --this is pseudo code
    SET @pointer += 1
END
```

So for the first byte (of the 32 available in that case) the value would be `00000000` before the `WHILE` loop and would become `00111000`.

I need help with that line `SET @byteArray[@pointer] = 1`.

Do you know a way I can achieve this?

**EDIT**

I'm looking for something like below but with SQL, not C#.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[32];
int bitIndex = 0;
int byteIndex = bitIndex / 8;
int bitInByteIndex = bitIndex % 8;
byte mask = (byte)(1 << bitInByteIndex);
byteArray[byteIndex] |= mask; //especially this line...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set bit in a varbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53355837/11683)

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, I already went through that post and I was wondering if it's possible to avoid converting the whole byte array to a string and convert it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up with a solution inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357680/11922370) (thanks to @GSerg).

Here it is:

```
DECLARE @varcharByteArray NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @varcharByteArray = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @byteArray, 1)

WHILE @pointer <= @endIndex
BEGIN
    SET @byteIndex = @pointer / 8
    SET @bitInByteIndex = @pointer % 8
    SET @byteState = CONVERT(BINARY(1), '0x' + SUBSTRING(@varcharByteArray, (@byteIndex * 2) + 3, 2), 1)

    IF @bitState = 1
        -- set bit to 1
        SET @byteState |= POWER(2, @bitInByteIndex)
    ELSE
        -- set bit to 0
        SET @byteState &= ~POWER(2, @bitInByteIndex)

    SET @varcharByteArray = SUBSTRING(@varcharByteArray, 1, (@byteIndex * 2) + 2) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @byteState, 1), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(@varcharByteArray, (@byteIndex * 2) + 5, LEN(@varcharByteArray))

    SET @pointer += 1
END

SET @byteArray = CONVERT(BINARY(32), @varcharByteArray, 1)
```

I find that solution a bit cumbersome but it does the job. I'll update this post if I found a more elegant way to do the same thing.